# Netbeans: how to Incorporate combobox and radiobuttons together?

Tags: netbeans, combobox, radio-button

In Netbeans If suppose I want the user to choose between a tour package Normal or Deluxe via radio button and I want them to select their destination from London , India and Australia via list and the value of each destination along with their respective packages are different.

Comment: int n = 0;
if(r1.isSelected ()==true)
{if (l1.isSelectedIndex(0) ==true)
    n+=25000;}
{
if (l1.isSelectedIndex(1) ==true)
n+=3500;}

{   if(l1.isSelectedIndex(2) ==true)
 n+=35000;
jt1.setText(""+n);}
{
    if(r2.isSelected()==true)
    if (l1.isSelectedIndex(0)==true)
       n+=45000;}{
if (l1.isSelectedIndex(1)==true)
        n+=60000;}{
if (l1.isSelectedIndex(2)==true)
        n+=50000;
jt1.setText(""+n);

Comment: but it's not completely working

Comment: Please don't post your code as comment, because it is too hard to read there. Please edit your question (there is an _edit_ button below your question) and add the code to your original post.

Comment: It's ok if your code is _not completely working._ But please tell us, what is working and what not. The more information you provide, the more likely it is that you will get a (correct) answer.